# How to practice Hadoop online?

Tags: java, hadoop

Is there a way to find an online Hadoop database and practice on it using Java?

I found that you can practice on www.gethue.com, but I don't think you can do it using java.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Cloudera Live](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products-and-services/cloudera-live.html).
It's in beta, but seems to work pretty well.

Comment: cloudera live redirects you to www.gethue.com

Comment: oops, didn't know that...

Answer (score 0):

I made a small list of free offers enabling you to manage your own hadoop cluster. It's not technically an available database, but you can fill these clusters with the data you want.

Here is the list :

- [Microsoft Azure HDInsight](http://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/pricing/details/hdinsight/) : they offer you 150€ to spend on their products. You can rent a Hadoop cluster and work on it.
- [Qubole](http://www.qubole.com/) : they give you preconfigured Hadoop clusters, you have 75 computing hours for free
- [Joyent](http://www.joyent.com/products/compute-service) : you can have one VM for free for a year.

You may also try [amazon's Elastic Map Reduce](http://aws.amazon.com/fr/elasticmapreduce/), although I'm not sure this specific offer is included in their free trial. An advantage of using it is you can access free datasets more easily (for instance, [this one](http://aws.amazon.com/datasets/8172056142375670)).

Please also note that all these services (except Qubole) require a credit card for registration.

Comment: Thank you, i'm trying qubole